# Flex container gets height wrong Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I am having a flex container, with two children(the blue ones), one of which has a height of *600px*.

Accordingly, the parent should have taken it's height and made it's other child to be of the same height as well, as it is correctly being done on chrome.

[image: On Chrome v75.0.3]

**On Chrome v75.0.3**

Although, on Safari, the parent doesn't derive it's height from it's largest child, height.

[image: On Safari v13.0]

**On Safari v13.0**

Below is the `temp.htm` file, which I am using for reproducing the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%; background-color: #ff0">

<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
    <div style="background-color: #00f; width: 75%; margin: 50px; flex-basis: content">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #00f; margin: 50px; width: 25%; height: 600px; flex-basis: content">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
    <div style="background-color: #f00; width: 75%; margin: 50px; flex-basis: content">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #f00; margin: 50px; width: 25%; height: 600px; flex-basis: content">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried to add `display:-webkit-flex` for the flex container ?

Comment: @KareemDabbeet Actually, I want my code to work on multiple browsers, and the version of safari I am using supports flex, so if I use both flex and -webkit-flex, that wouldn't work on safari, and if I use only -webkit-flex, it might affect the experience on browsers other than safari.

Comment: Add `flex-shrink: 0` to the nested containers. https://jsfiddle.net/k1c5mhg3/2/

Comment: This worked!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

On the body:

```
// remove the following
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;

// add
  flex-wrap: wrap;
```

On the flex rows (that contain your coloured blocks):

```
// add this
  flex: 0 0 100%;
```